# Prime number size and RSA decryption

Tags: rsa

Is there a former proof for why larger prime numbers make RSA securer? Maybe a theorem to show that it takes much more time to find out the private key if primes are larger?

Answer (score 2):

The idea that RSA relies on the difficulty of integer factorization is called the [RSA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem). The efficiency of the different methods to perform integer factorization is discussed in a [similar article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Theoretically, there may be more efficient methods to perform factorization; we cannot prove that there aren't.  Therefore we cannot prove RSA is secure either.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the prime numbers does not necessarily lead to an increase in security of the RSA. As an example, when the private exponent is less than $\frac{N^{\frac{1}{4}}}{3}$, Wiener's attack is able to factor $N$ in the polynomial time.

There are other attacks against this system, which can be found in ["Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem"](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/RSA-survey.pdf) and ["Thirty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem"](https://cryptjwang.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/rsa_attacks.pdf).